# Get attachment url using an attachment ID attribute in backend view of a Gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

If a Gutenberg block has an attachment ID attribute stored, is there are way to dynamically get the url of a specific thumbnail size using that ID?

The attribute will be stored in the block like this:

```
 imageID: {
     type: 'integer',
 },
```

And the idea is to dynamically show that image in the Gutenberg editor view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem a few weeks ago. It had me baffled for a while but you can do it using [withSelect()()](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-data/#withSelect) and `getMedia()`. In a nut shell, we are going to have to get the media object from the ID that we have. Look inside that object for the thumbnail object. Then we will get the `source_url` property. Your file should look something like:

```
// Block image preview
const blockEdit = createElement("div", null, 

    // If image defined, get the source_url
    const imageThumbURL = props.imageObj ? props.imageObj.media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url : null

    createElement("img", {
        src: imageThumbURL
    })
)

// Use withSelect(x)(y) to load image url on page load
const fieldData = withSelect( (select, props) => {
    // Get the image ID
    const imageId = props.attributes.imageID

    // Create "props.imageObj"
    return { 
        // If image defined, get the image "media" object
        imageObj: imageId ? select("core").getMedia(imageId) : null
    }
})(blockEdit)

wp.blocks.registerBlockType('plugin-namespace/block-name', {
    attributes: {
        imageID: {
            type: 'Number'
        }
    },
    edit: fieldData
}
```

The above is untested but I used that solution to allow my media item to load when the page is loaded by using it's ID. Hopefully this helps.